# $a\mid bc$ where $a$, $b$ are relatively prime implies $a\mid c$ in a unique factorization domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility, unique-factorization-domains

I'm asked to solve

> If $R$ is a unique factorization domain  and for $a$, $b$ two elements that are relatively prime in $R$ and $a$ divides $bc$, then $a$ divides $c$.

While trying to prove this, I've proved that $a$ and $c$ are associate. 
And this is more than what is required, so I'm afraid I've done something wrong.
Can anybody help me?

First of all, if $a$ was irreducible, then it is prime and we are done.
If it  wasn't then it can be written as a finite product of irreducible elements, $b$ and $c$ can be written similarly.

$a$ divides $bc$ implies that $bc = ka$ for some $k \in R$.
Now since the irreducible elements need to be associate and $a$ doesn't divide $b$.
the irreducible factors of $a$ are associate to the ones of $c$. Which implies that $a$ is associate to $c$.

Comment: Show your efforts. Then maybe someone can indeed tell you whether you did something wrong.

Comment: @drhab i wrote everything

Comment: The last line should read "Which implies that  $a$ *divides* $c$.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy proof that does not require unique factorisation, just the existence of least common multiples. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and a least common multiple of $a,b$ exists, that least common multiple must be (the association class of) $ab$. Now $bc$ is by hypothesis a multiple of $a$ and it is clearly a multiple of $b$, so by the defining property of least common multiples it is a multiple of $ab$. We have $ab\mid bc$, and one can simplify that by$~b$ to give $a\mid c$.

Comment: An easy simple solution. Thank u so much :) @Marc van Leeuwen

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicion is correct: you can't deduce that $a$ and $c$ are associate. Think to the case $a=6$, $b=5$ and $c=12$ in the integers: $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $a$ divides $bc=60$, but $a$ and $c$ are certainly not associate.

Here's a possible proof by induction on the number of terms in a factorization of $a$, let's call it the *length* of $a$.

If the length of $a$ is $1$, then $a$ is irreducible (and so prime); since $a$ does not divide $b$, but divides $bc$, it must divide $c$.

Now suppose the assertion is true for elements that have length $n$ and assume $a$ has length $n+1$. Then we can write $a=pA$, where the length of $A$ is $n$ (fill in details) and $p$ is prime. Note that $A$ and $b$ are coprime (fill in details).

Since $p$ divides $a$ and so divides $bc$, we get that $p$ divides $bc$. But $p$ does not divide $b$, because $a$ and $b$ are coprime (fill in details). Therefore $p$ divides $c$ and we can write $c=pC$. So we have that $a=pA$ divides $bc=pbC$ and so $A$ divides $bC$. Since $A$ has length $n$ and is coprime with $b$, the induction hypothesis tells us that $A$ divides $C$: $C=AD$. Therefore
$$
c=pC=pAD=aD
$$
and so $a$ divides $c$.

Fill in the details and the proof is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The same proof that works for $\mathbb Z$ works for every UFD.

For each prime $p$ in $R$,
let $v_p(x)$ be the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $x$.
Then $a$ divides $bc$ iff $v_p(a) \le v_p(bc)$ for all $p$.
Now,  $ v_p(bc) = v_p(b) + v_p(c )$ and so $v_p(a) \le  v_p(b) + v_p(c )$.
Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, $v_p(b)=0$ whenever $v_p(a)>0$. Hence $v_p(a)>0$ implies $v_p(a) \le v_p(c )$ for all $p$. This means that $a$ divides $c$.

If the proof above is too abstract, here it is made concrete:

Since $a$ divides $bc$, we can write $ad=bc$, for some $d\in R$. Now consider the factorization into irreducibles (or primes):
$$
u_a p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}\ u_d p_1^{\delta_1}\cdots p_n^{\delta_n}
=
u_b p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_n^{\beta_n}\ u_c p_1^{\gamma_1}\cdots p_n^{\gamma_n}
$$
for some units $u_*$. Here I have used the same set of primes for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. Just use a zero exponent if a prime does not divide one of those. It does no harm.

All this means that $\alpha_i+\delta_i = \beta_i+\gamma_i$.
Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, $\beta_i=0$ whenever $\alpha_i>0$ and so in this case $\alpha_i\le\alpha_i+\delta_i = 0+\gamma_i=\gamma_i$. This means that $a$ divides $c$.

Comment: I'm sorry to till u that's my first time to hear about the exponent of p ! Ive just edited the question and wrote what i have done . will u till me have i made sth wrong ?

Comment: yes it is much clearer now .. thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

My proof is more elaborate version of answer provided by user Ihf. Following proof is common strategy to approach this kind of  problem (involving unique factorization domain).

**Proof:** Since $a\mid bc$, $\exists x\in R$ such that $ax=bc$. Suppose $a,b,c,x$ are non zero (otherwise problem is trivial or don’t make sense).

*Case (1)*: $a,b,c,x$ are non unit. Since $R$ is unique factorization ring, each element can be written as finite product of irreducible. So $ax=bc$ becomes $$a_1\cdots a_n x_1\cdots x_m = b_1\cdots b_p c_1\cdots c_q.$$
By uniqueness part, each $a_i$ is associate of either $b_j$ or $c_j$ (index $j$ depends on $i$). We claim each $a_i$ is associate of $c_j$. Assume towards contradiction, $\exists 1\leq i\leq n$ such that $a_i$ is associate of some $b_j$. In particular, $a_i\mid b_j\mid b$. So $a_i\mid b$ and $a_i\mid a$. Since $\gcd (a,b)=1_R$, we have $a_i\mid 1_R$. Which implies $a_i$ is unit. Which contradicts $a_i$ is irreducible. Thus each $a_i$ is associate of $c_j$. WLOG, assume $a_i$ is associate of $c_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Since $R$ is integral domain, $a_i$ is associate of $c_i$$\implies$$c_i=u_ia_i$ where $u_i\in R$ is a unit. So
$$\begin{align} c &= c_1\cdots c_n c_{n+1}\cdots c_q \\ &= u_1a_1\cdots u_na_n c_{n+1}\cdots c_q \\ &= (u_1\cdots u_n)(a_1\cdots a_n) c_{n+1}\cdots c_q \\ &= u a c_{n+1}\cdots c_q
\end{align}$$
where $u=u_1\cdots u_n$. Thus $a\mid c$.

*Case (2)*: $a$ is unit. Then $c=1_Rc=(aa^{-1})c=a(a^{-1}c)$. Thus $a\mid c$.

*Case (3)*: $b$ is unit. Multiply $b^{-1}$ on both side of $ax=bc$, we have $c=b^{-1}ax$. Thus $a\mid c$.

*Case (4)*: $c$ is unit. Multiply $c^{-1}$ on both side of $ax=bc$, we have $b=axc^{-1}$. So $a\mid b$ and $a\mid a$. Since $\gcd (a,b)=1_R$, we have $a\mid 1_R$. Which implies $a$ is unit. By case (2), $a\mid c$.

*Case (5)*: $x$ is unit. Multiply $x^{-1}$ on both side of $ax=bc$, we have $a=bcx^{-1}$. So $b\mid a$ and $b\mid b$. Since $\gcd (a,b)=1_R$, we have $b\mid 1_R$. Which implies $b$ is unit. By case (3), $a\mid c$.